# Flutter head up notification not showing when app receive first notification from Firebase push notification on `iOS` only

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase push notification on my app.

As the title mentioned, my app not able to show the head up notification for the first initial pushed notification sent by my backend server. when this happens, my app is in the foreground

Any notification sent after that, is working fine.

This only happens on ios devices

Upon receiving the initial notification from my backend server, the `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` event is activated, allowing me to retrieve the `message.data` in my console. However, the expected heads-up notification does not appear to be displayed.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      Utilities.showLogWhenDebug("Got a message whilst in the foreground!", message.data.toString());
    });
```

Does anyone possess insight into the potential reasons behind this occurrence, as well as potential solutions? Any assistance provided would be greatly valued.

*Note*: i do not want to use `flutter_local_notifications` to achieve this, i want to use the original head up notification provided by Firebase itself, thank you

Expected result

- app able to show the head up notification when the first notification is sent from backend server